# Regular-Expression Phone number validation with spaces and characters with minimun digits

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-2016

I have less skill for the Regex and I have a quick question. I need to validate phone number input with regEx.

Explanation/expression will be really appreciated. The Phone numbers can be any of the following formats:

```
(94) 123 345
(94).456.7899
(94)-456-7899
94-456-7899
+94 456 7899
94 456 7899
0094 456 7899
(94) 123
122 3454
1223454
```

**1) Number can include spaces and characters or without characters.**
 **2) It should have minimum 5 digits without spaces and characters.** (I stuck at this point)

*1st try*

```
export const basicPhoneNumber = value =>
value && !/^\+?\d+$/i.test(value) 
? 'Invalid phone number' 
: undefined;
```

*2nd try*

```
  export const basicPhoneNumber = value =>
  value && !/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4,})/i.test(value) 
  ? 'Invalid phone number' 
  : undefined;
```

Thanks a lot for all your help and have a good one!

Comment: Do you want to add characters in phone number ?

Comment: yes, It  can be with characters or without characters. (123)-456-7899 or 123 456899

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phone number validation with regular expression is rather complicated, especially in such cases, yet we can try with an expression similar to:

```
^\+?\(?([0-9]{2,4})[)\s.-]+([0-9]{3,4})([\s.-]+([0-9]{3,4}))?$
```

which would likely fail with some desired instances that are not listed, regardless that some inputs such as (000) 000-0000 are not really phone numbers.

```js
const regex = /^\+?\(?([0-9]{2,4})[)\s.-]+([0-9]{3,4})([\s.-]+([0-9]{3,4}))?$/gmi;
const str = `(94) 123 345
(94).456.7899
(94)-456-7899
94-456-7899
+94 456 7899
94 456 7899
0094 456 7899
(94) 123
122 3454`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/y5mSg8/1/)

#### Edit

For allowing `12234554`, we would make an optional group for `([)\s.-]+)?`,

```
^\+?\(?([0-9]{2,4})([)\s.-]+)?([0-9]{3,4})([\s.-]+([0-9]{3,4}))?$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/CZJK4a/1/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's almost working fine. But can you edit it to allow phone number without spaces eg '12234554'.?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is to validate the phone numbers with your listed criteria, you can consider stripping out all non-digit characters first, then test with RegExp.

Not only it is a lot easier, it is also much easier to understand.

```js
// Sample data
const numbers = [
  '(94) 123 345',
  '(94).456.7899',
  '(94)-456-7899',
  '94-456-7899',
  '+94 456 7899',
  '94 456 7899',
  '0094 456 7899',
  '(94) 123',
  '122 3454'
]

// The validation function
const validate = value => {
  value = value.replace(/\D|(^0+)/g, '');
  return /^\d{5,}$/.test(value);
}

// Tests
numbers.forEach(function(phone){
  console.log(validate(phone), `"${phone}"`);
});
```

#### RegExp explanation:

**`/\D|(^0+)/g`**

1. `\D` matches all non-digit character.
2. `(^0+)` matches when there is at least 1 leading 0 character(s).

**`/^\d{5,}$/`**

Matches when the string starts and ends with a digit, and when the string consists of at least 5 digits, without any non-digits.